# Scope Store not working for custom category attribute

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, scope, scope-switcher

We are using Magento 2.2.6 and created a new category attribute. But the store_view scope is not working. I searched already in the database and also diverse blogs on the internet but don't get a reason why.

We did reindex and upgrade. The value of our attribute is also saving to the database - but seems to use globally.

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'vendor_short_description',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'vendor_short_description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'group' => 'Content'
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a default bug but there some workaround for this as well.

**step1** Create a new module `Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="categoryCustomAttributes" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Category\DataProvider" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**step2** Create a file `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Category\DataProvider.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Category;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function afterPrepareMeta(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider $subject, $result)
    {
        $meta = array_replace_recursive($result, $this->_prepareFieldsMeta(
            $this->_getFieldsMap(),
            $subject->getAttributesMeta($this->eavConfig->getEntityType('catalog_category'))
        ));
        return $meta;
    }

    public function _prepareFieldsMeta($fieldsMap, $fieldsMeta)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($fieldsMap as $fieldSet => $fields) {
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                if (isset($fieldsMeta[$field])) {
                    $result[$fieldSet]['children'][$field]['arguments']['data']['config'] = $fieldsMeta[$field];
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function _getFieldsMap()
    {
        $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
        // Adjust per your needs here
        $fields['content'][] = 'long_description';
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: [Magento 2: Custom category attribute is missing scope](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258699/magento-2-custom-category-attribute-is-missing-scope/258710).

It is a magento bug discussed here:https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13440.

This solution worked for me: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13440#issuecomment-436712363